# jquery if link = page url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url, href

ok pretty simple but i dont know how...

i just want to make an active state (probably just make it bold)

my menu is  ul-li

i cant figure out how to write it so if the url matches with one of the links, make the link bold

please help

thanks for your time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a short way to select links like that:

```
$('ul > li a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').css('font-weight','bold');
```

Or perhaps better like this, which does an exact match of both `pathname` attributes:

```
$('ul > li a[href]').filter(function() {
    return this.href.pathname === window.location.pathname;
}).css('font-weight','bold');
```

If you're using the full domain in the `href`, you could change it to:

```
return this.href === window.location;
```

Comment: Minor correction, but it should be "this.pathname" instead of "this.href.pathname".

Comment: `return this.href === window.location.href;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great solution I have used:

```
$(function(){
       $("a").each(function(){
               if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
                       $(this).addClass("selected");
               }
       });
});
```

Source - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/highlight-all-links-to-current-page/

Comment: I don't think it works. `href` could be `https://www.-----.com/folder1/folder2/name-of-page` while `window.location.pathname` is just `/folder1/folder2/name-of-page`